# Pandas DataFrame: Replace a column by a list with a new column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` and want to replace a column with a new one. The column should have a new name and a list gives its content. I can do this in two different ways. See the code below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Alice','Bob','Charlie'],
    'Age': [18,19,20]
})
print('df=\n',df,'\n')

marks = [50,60,90]


# Drop and add 
df1 = df.drop(columns = ['Age'])
df1['Marks'] = marks
print('df1=\n',df1,'\n')
print() 

# Rename and assign
df1 = df.rename(columns={'Age':'Marks'})
df1 = df1.assign(Marks=marks) 
print('df1=\n',df1)
```

Output:

```
    df=
       Name  Age
0    Alice   18
1      Bob   19
2  Charlie   20 

df1=
       Name  Marks
0    Alice     50
1      Bob     60
2  Charlie     90 


df1=
       Name  Marks
0    Alice     50
1      Bob     60
2  Charlie     90
```

My question is: Can there be a more elegant or oneliner to perform this "replace column" operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `drop` and `assign` in a single line:

```
df = df.drop(columns='Age').assign(Marks=marks)
```

If your new column name has a space in it:

```
df =  df.drop(columns='Age').assign(**{"Marks Obtained": marks})
```

Comment: What if I have a two-word column header, say, "Marks Obtained"? Then I think `assign` won't work and `rename` plus `update will be the only option, right?

Comment: You can still use `assign` like in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can perform this assign and drop with this code

```
df = df.assign(Marks=marks).drop(columns=['Age'])
```

And now you get what you want.

Comment: I think you need to use `df =df.assign(Marks=marks).drop(columns=['Age'])`. Else, it doesn't get updated.

Comment: @hbaromega why would you think that? This should work perfectly fine; the two ops are interchangable.

Comment: @Quang I wanted to mean, you need update `df` by saying `df =df.assign(Marks=marks).drop(columns=['Age'])`. The `=` seems to be needed.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I've shown him that with that expression he can achieve what he requested

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) together with [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)

```
# in-place
df.rename(columns={"Age": "Marks"}, inplace=True)
df.update({"Marks": marks})
```

Comment: in-place is working but somehow the new dataframe is showing `None`. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. It turns out that `update()` just updates in-place and returns `None`. I have editted the answer to only keep the in-place solution.